# Application failed 2 times due to AM container for appattempt_ exited with exitCode: 0

Tags: apache-spark

When I submit my spark program, it fails at the end but with a ExitCode:0 as shown in the [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/synDU.png).
The program should write a table on hive and despite the failure, the table was created successfully.
But I can't figure out the origin of the error. Can you help please.

Yarn logs -appID gives the following output [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rMM74.png)

Comment: can you add more details like whats the deploy mode, yarn-client or cluster? also do a yarn logs -applicationId <appID> > test.log and then paste the contents of test.log

Comment: please check yarn logs or post that logs here to find actual reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved my problem. In fact today I suprisingly got another error from the same program saying

**ERROR** CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Executor self-exiting due to : Driver X:37478 disassociated! Shutting down.

And I found so many solutions talking about memory or timeOut.

What did the trick is just that I **forgot to close my sparkSession** (***spark.close()***).